IntelliJ plugin to view maven plugin versions (direct and idirect)
I am using "Dependency Analyzer" plugin in IntelliJ in order to see versions of all dependencies from the pom:

It works pretty well for dependencies. Just when I want to see also versions of plugins which are in pom, for instance I want to see version of surefire plugin:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
</plugin>

I am not able to find it in this plugin:

I was able to resolve all plugins using the command:
 mvn dependency:resolve-plugins But I would like to be able to have a graphical tool to analyze all plugins - also those which are declared indirectly. Is there any IntelliJ plugin which has this functionality?
